# Centos 7.4 pxe boot fails to find "installation sources" that using a ftp stie

Tags: centos, ipxe

I think this is related to --url parameter but I have tested the ftp path and I can access the ftp from another system.

When the pxe boot loads the kickstart file and starts the installation GUI, "Installation Sources" is grayed out because it can't file the ftp location, it eventually times out, and I can check my ftp path, but it is correct. but installation sources rejects the path, and I can never proceed with the install

[image]

Comment: This is what my kick start file looks like, only two commands

Comment: install
url --url=ftp://128.101.1.1/RemoteInstall/Images/Linux/CENTOS_7.4_ALL